# DateTime question in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, datetime

Ok, so I need to find the date of Monday this week programmatically.

For example, for this week Monday was on the 9th, so the date I need is: 09/11/2009

And when we roll over to next week it needs to calculate: 16/11/2009

I have tried doing this myself but I can't see how to do the arithmetic, thank you.

Answer (score 4):

C#:

```
date.AddDays(1 - (date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday ? 7 : (int)date.DayOfWeek));
```

VB.NET:

```
date.AddDays(1 - IIf((date.DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Sunday), 7, date.DayOfWeek))
```

Comment: When I use that I get a lot of syntax errors, and when I clean it up to what .NET might accept I get this error: Value of type 'Date' cannot be converted to 'Integer'

Comment: That's because that is C# and not vb.net

Comment: I'd use If instead of Iif though if possible (short-circuiting + type safe)

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim thisMonday As Date = Now.AddDays((Now.DayOfWeek - 1) * -1).Date
```

If today is a Sunday it gives the following Monday otherwise, gives the Monday this week.

Answer (score 1):

```
Return givenDate.AddDays(1 - CType(IIf((givenDate.DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Sunday), 7, givenDate.DayOfWeek), Double))
```

If `givenDate` is a Sunday, counts back to the preceding Monday. Includes a `CType` to cast the `IIf` result to a Double to work with `Option Strict On`.