# Finding the date of monday in a week with VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, datetime

I need to find a way to find the date (DD/MM/YYYY) of the Monday for any week we're on.

For example, for this week, monday would be 09/11/2009, and if this were next week it'd be 16/11/2009.

I managed to get somewhere in the forms of code, but all I got was 'cannot convert to Integer' errors. I was using Date.Today and AddDays().

Thanks for any help. :)

Comment: Same question as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1706589/datetime-question-in-vb-net ??

Answer (score 40):

If Sunday is the first day of week, you can simply do this:

```
Dim today As Date = Date.Today
Dim dayDiff As Integer = today.DayOfWeek - DayOfWeek.Monday
Dim monday As Date = today.AddDays(-dayDiff)
```

If Monday is the first day of week:

```
Dim today As Date = Date.Today
Dim dayIndex As Integer = today.DayOfWeek
If dayIndex < DayOfWeek.Monday Then
    dayIndex += 7 'Monday is first day of week, no day of week should have a smaller index
End If
Dim dayDiff As Integer = dayIndex - DayOfWeek.Monday
Dim monday As Date = today.AddDays(-dayDiff)
```

Comment: You can set my answer as accepted then :-) Also if you want to comment something to us (like your thanks message) you should add a comment to your question or edit your question instead of adding an answer. Also, welcome on Stack Overflow!

Comment: Does this actually work if the day is Sunday?  When I tried it I got the date of the **following** Monday, not the previous Monday.

Comment: Reason it doesn't work on Sunday:  The value of DayOfWeek.Sunday is 0 and DayOfWeek.Monday is 1.  Therefore dayDiff is -1 and (-dayDiff) is +1.  So the value of the variable monday will be today (Sunday) plus 1 day.  Therefore you may need to add a test along the lines of If today.DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Sunday Then monday = monday.AddDays(-7)

Comment: @SimonTewsi: It works on Sunday... If you consider that the week starts on Sunday. Otherwise you can adjust dayDiff. If it's a negative number, add 7 days to it.

Comment: What if I want to start the week on a Saturday?

Answer (score 9):

DateTime.DayOfWeek is an enum that indicates what day a given date is.  As Monday is 1, you can find the Monday of the current week using the following code:

```
Dim monday As DateTime = Today.AddDays((Today.DayOfWeek - DayOfWeek.Monday) * -1)
```

Comment: This implies `Dim monday As DateTime = Today.AddDays((DayOfWeek.Monday - Today.DayOfWeek))`

Answer (score 2):

```
=Format(DateAdd("d", (-1 * WeekDay(Date.Today()) + 2), Date.Today()), "dd/MM/yyyy")
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple method should get you what you want:

```
    private static DateTime GetMondayForWeek(DateTime inputDate)
    {
        int daysFromMonday = inputDate.DayOfWeek - DayOfWeek.Monday;
        return inputDate.AddDays(-daysFromMonday);
    }
```

You could also extend it for any day that you want as well:

```
    private static DateTime GetDayForWeek(DateTime inputDate, DayOfWeek inputDay)
    {
        int daysAway = inputDate.DayOfWeek - inputDay;
        return inputDate.AddDays(-daysAway);
    }
```

To call the first example just use something like:

```
DateTime mondayDate = GetMondayForWeek(new DateTime(2009, 11, 15));
Console.WriteLine(mondayDate);
```

Comment: feeding C# to the new guy?  (see tags)

Comment: Ahhhh, didn't see the VB tag. I normally ask questions, not answer them so a little new to the whole answering scene.  Unfortunately I don't even have VB on my machine.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach if Monday is the first day, is this:

```
 Dim today As Date = Date.Today
                Dim dayDiff As Integer = today.DayOfWeek - DayOfWeek.Monday
                Dim monday As Date = today.AddDays(-dayDiff)

                dayDiff = DayOfWeek.Saturday - today.DayOfWeek + 1
                Dim sunday As Date = today.AddDays(dayDiff)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a day of week method that you can use

```
Dim instance As DateTime
Dim value As DayOfWeek

value = instance.DayOfWeek
```

see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.dayofweek.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I just did this in a project I'm working on --I promise, it's correct.  This is a method that returns the nth monday after the given date.  If the given date is a monday, it returns the next monday.

```
Public Function GetSubsequentMonday(ByVal startDate As DateTime, ByVal subsequentWeeks As Integer) As DateTime
    Dim dayOfWeek As Integer = CInt(startDate.DayOfWeek)
    Dim daysUntilMonday As Integer = (Math.Sign(dayOfWeek) * (7 - dayOfWeek)) + 1
    'number of days until the next Monday
    Return startDate.AddDays(CDbl((daysUntilMonday + (7 * (subsequentWeeks - 1)))))
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Following on from my comments to Meta-Knight's answer, here is a short function that makes the correction I mention in the comments:

```
Public Function GetFirstOfLastWeek() As DateTime
Dim today As DateTime, daysSinceMonday As Integer
    today = DateTime.Today
    daysSinceMonday = today.DayOfWeek - DayOfWeek.Monday
    If daysSinceMonday < 0 Then
        daysSinceMonday += 7
    End If
    Return today.AddDays(-daysSinceMonday)  
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

And if your week starts from Monday then you can use something like this:

```
DateTime mondayDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(((DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday?7: (int)DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek) - 1)*-1);

DateTime sundayDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(7 - (DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday?7: (int)DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek ));
```

Answer (score 0):

```vb
Dim dayOfWeek = CInt(DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek)
Dim startOfWeek = DateTime.Today.AddDays(+1 * dayOfWeek).ToShortDateString
Dim endOfWeek = DateTime.Today.AddDays(6 + dayOfWeek).AddSeconds(+1).ToShortDateString
MessageBox.Show(startOfWeek)
MessageBox.Show(endOfWeek)
```

**Example:**
If today is `03/09/2020`,
`startOfWeek` will be `07/09/2020` and
`endOfWeek` will be `13/09/2020`.