# Find the Monday of a Week, Based on "Date" Field

Tags: vb.net

This is my issue, I want to return the Monday of a given week in date format.

Here I have my effort so far.

Code:

```
Dim Diff
Dim cDate
Dim prday
prday = [table.datefield]
Diff = Cint(0 - (Weekday(prday, 2)))
cDate = DateAdd("d", Diff, prday)
Result = cDate
```

However, this rather unfortunately returns 24/12/1899. Not exactly what I want.. 2013 would be nice. Any tips for where I went wrong?

Note:

The specific date which is pulled out of the database table is done in a different application. This code is supposed to generate a date which will be shown on a label.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1710487/finding-the-date-of-monday-in-a-week-with-vb-net

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only issue is how you want to treat Sunday dates.

```
'Sunday as first day of week
Dim someDate As DateTime = DateTime.Parse("Apr 28, 2013")
'calculate monday
'note:  for Sunday this returns next Monday, i.e Apr 28, 2013 returns Apr 29th
Dim monDate As DateTime = someDate.AddDays(DayOfWeek.Monday - someDate.DayOfWeek)

'Monday as first day of week
Dim someDate As DateTime = DateTime.Parse("Apr 28, 2013")
'calculate monday
If someDate.DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Sunday Then someDate = someDate.AddDays(-1)
Dim monDate As DateTime = someDate.AddDays(DayOfWeek.Monday - someDate.DayOfWeek)
```

Answer (score 2):

Define an extension method

```
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices

Module DateExtensions

    <Extension()> 
    Public Function GetMonday(ByVal dt As DateTime) as DateTime
        While dt.DayOfWeek <> DayOfWeek.Monday
           dt = dt.AddDays(-1)
        End While
        return dt
    End Function
End Module
```

And call it

```
prday = prday.GetMonday()
```

Or we could make it generic

```
Public Function GetPreviousDayOfWeek(ByVal dt As DateTime, prevDay As DayOfWeek) as DateTime
    While dt.DayOfWeek <> prevDay
       dt = dt.AddDays(-1)
    End While
    return dt
End Function
```

As pointed out by @dbasnett a math is faster than a loop and we could handle the situation when Sunday is the first day of week. So a better approach should be

```
Public Function GetMonday(ByVal dt As DateTime) as DateTime
    Dim diff = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.FirstDayOfWeek - DayOfWeek.Monday
    dt = dt.AddDays(diff)
    return  dt.AddDays(DayOfWeek.Monday - dt.DayOfWeek)
End Function
```