# VBA how many mondays till date and VBA errors

Tags: vba, excel, date

I am attempting to write a script in VBA that will take a date as an input and then know if that date is from this week till next Monday or how many weeks longer than that it would be.

Edit: below part was resolved but, I could still use some assistance with the top.  I was foolishly using VB.Net code instead of VBA.

I looked at the page I will link below that seems to have given me a direction. 
[Finding the date of monday in a week with VB.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1710487/finding-the-date-of-monday-in-a-week-with-vb-net/1710573#1710573)

The problem was that I am not able to use the commands in my VBA code.  Its odd because it seems to have worked for everyone else but VBA wont let me use those commands myself. Would anyone be able to help me understand why? The following lines are the ones that came back red upon me adding the code into my excel VBA module.  "Date." is also not working.

```
Dim today As Date = Date.Today    
Dim dayIndex As Integer = today.DayOfWeek

dayIndex += 7

Dim dayDiff As Integer = dayIndex - DayOfWeek.Monday    
Dim monday As Date = today.AddDays(-dayDiff)
```

Comment: `I am attempting to write a script in VBA...` then you do not need the VB.NET tag.  Refer to the usage guidance text on the tags if you are unsure

Comment: in vba you cannot declare and assign a value to a variable on the same line.  Split them up: `Dim today As Date` and `today = Date` and so on.

Comment: and `dayIndex += 7` needs to be `dayIndex = dayIndex  + 7`

Comment: You are copy+pasting VB.NET code into the VBA editor. Of course it's not compiling - VB.NET is not VBA.

Comment: Thank you.  This assists with the bottom part of my question.  Is there any help that can be given to the top portion?

Comment: Look it up. Press F2 and find the `VBA.DateTime` module, you'll quickly find the functions available to you.

Comment: Now you are asking us to write code for you.  Please make an attempt in vba to do what you want, then come back with vba code when you get stuck.

Comment: See this, it will help: http://access.mvps.org/access/datetime/date0011.htm

Comment: Thank you all very much for your help.  I am going forward using the information provided by Kostas K.

Answer (score 1):

Without VBA you can use a formula:

```
=ABS(INT((WEEKDAY(A1-2)-A1+TODAY())/7))
```

A1 is the starting Date
2 correspond to Monday day of the week
divided by 7 to have the count of it
You can change Today() to any date in that case you count the number of Mondays between 2 dates

```
Sunday     1
Monday     2
Tuesday    3
Wednesday  4
Thursday   5
Friday     6
Saturday   7
```

You can change 2 in the formula to any number between 1 till 7 to correspond any WeekDay you need

**With VBA**
You need a UDF user defined function:

```
Function NumbWkDays(StartDate As Date, EndDate As Date, _
    Days As Long) As Integer

     ' Returns the number of qualifying days between (and including)
     ' StartDate and EndDate. Qualifying days are whole numbers where
     ' each digit represents a day of the week that should be counted,
     ' with Monday=1, Tuesday=2, etc. For example, all Mondays, Tuesdays
     ' and Thursdays are to be counted between the two dates, set
     ' WkDays = 124 on your worksheet.
     '

    Dim iDate As Date
    Dim strQdays As String

    strQdays = CStr(Days)
    NumbWkDays = 0

    For iDate = StartDate To EndDate
        If strQdays Like "*" & CStr(Weekday(iDate, vbMonday)) & "*" Then
            NumbWkDays = NumbWkDays + 1
        End If
    Next iDate

End Function
```

Then you have to use it as Formula:

```
=NumbWKdays(startdate,Enddate,1)
```

1 for Monday

To create UDF you have to:

- click Visual Basic under Developer Tab
- Insert
- Module
- Paste the code
  Then in the sheet use the function like above