# Finding the date of monday in a week with asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, datetime

I need to find the date of Monday this week.

For example, for this week Monday was on the 25th, so the date I need is: 25/02/2013

And when we roll over to next week it needs to calculate: 03/03/2013.

I tried to search but i cant find it for asp.net.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1706589/datetime-question-in-vb-net and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1710487/finding-the-date-of-monday-in-a-week-with-vb-net this has nothing to do with asp.net..

Comment: What's the first day of your week? Sunday? Monday?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
DateTime mondayDate = DateTime
                          .Today
                          .AddDays(((int)(DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek) * -1) + 1);
```

So for Today `{27/02/2013 12:00:00 AM}` it will give `{25/02/2013 12:00:00 AM}`

Comment: This works fine as long as Sunday is the first day of your week, so I assume this is the case for OP.

Answer (score 1):

Usage in C#:

```
dt.AddDays(1 - (dt.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday ? 7 : (int)dt.DayOfWeek));
```

Usage in VB.NET:

```
dt.AddDays(1 - If(dt.DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Sunday, 7, dt.DayOfWeek))
```

Reference: [DateTime question in VB.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1706608/468718)

Comment: If you are using at least VS 2008 you can also use the [`If`-operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb513985.aspx) in VB.NET: `If((date.DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Monday)`. Note that your code will not compile with `IIf` since it returns an object and must be casted(option strict presumed).

Comment: @TimSchmelter Thanx for point this, I have updated to `If` from `IIf`.. I'm not much good in VB.NET ;)

Comment: So, if `dt` is a Monday, this subtracts six days from it, giving a Tuesday... what?

Comment: @Rawling Thanks, I just tested this and it was failing for each Tuesdays to find the Mondays.. However I have updated code to fix this problem and now it should work as good as `Butter`.

Comment: But now if you give it a Monday it gives you the _previous_ Monday.

Comment: @Rawling Updated my answer. :| btw do you think this code snippet can handle weeks which start on other days than Sunday as First day of week ?

Comment: The whole `If` part is now superfluous, because `DayOfWeek.Monday` is already `1`. The _original code_ mapped `Sunday` to `7` in order to map a Sunday to the _previous_ Monday, i.e. to treat Monday as the first day of the week; if Sunday is the first day of the week then it isn't necessary to have any special cases. For any other day of the week starting the week, you'd need something more elaborate.